# Trying to prevent a security group from applying to other folders/files

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, acl

I'm trying to make it so that `$ADNameRO` and `$ADNameRW` (that I've created below) don't get applied to folders below it but let the rest of the permissions be inherited.

I've tried to change the propagation flag for those two strings so that it only applied to the Folder and Files that it is added to, but it still get's added to the sub files and folders...

I thought that I might need to change the InheritanceFlags to `Object` for both of those strings, but when I changed that manually (through Windows GUI) it didn't seem to work correctly...

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
function New-Ace {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [Security.Principal.NTAccount]$Account,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
    [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$Permissions = 'ReadAndExecute',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]$InheritanceFlags = 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
    [Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]$PropagationFlags = 'None',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
    [Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]$Type = 'Allow'
  )

  New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $Account, $Permissions, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $Type
  )
}

$domain = 'ESG.INTL'
$administrators = ([wmi]"Win32_Sid.Sid='S-1-5-32-544'").AccountName
$ADDomainUsers = "$domain\Domain Users"

$acl = Get-Acl $path

$administrators, "$domain\Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object {
  $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $_ 'FullControl'))
}
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRW 'Modify'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRO 'ReadAndExecute'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADDomainUsers 'ReadAndExecute'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting access permissions to folders and files without inheritance requires two ACEs: one for "this folder only" and one for "files only". For the former set both inheritance and propagation flags to `None`, for the latter set inheritance flags to `ObjectInherit` and propagation flags to `InheritOnly`:

```
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRW 'Modify' 'None'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRW 'Modify' 'ObjectInherit' 'InheritOnly'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRO 'ReadAndExecute' 'None'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRO 'ReadAndExecute' 'ObjectInherit' 'InheritOnly'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I need to read a little more on ACE creation. It makes sense when you spell it out like that, but I would have never thought I needed to create new ones each time. However, when I run it like that the folder that is created doesn't give any rights to that security group... It is rather odd because under advanced properties it is showing permissions, but under the Properties - Security tab both new groups show, but all permissions are completely blank...

Comment: It looks like the image I added in this question: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753850/set-acl-folder-permissions-not-applying-correctly-with-my-powershell-script)

Comment: If you scroll down the "permissions" listbox in the properties dialog you'll notice a check mark in the line "Special permissions". The other lines only show check marks for specific combinations of permissions and inheritance/propagation flags. Otherwise they're empty.

Comment: Wow... I was so tired yesterday that I forgot the Special Permissions check box... It makes a lot more sense this morning and I've corrected all of my scripts that use this now. Thanks for your help!